# Why can't a function execute a function in JavaScript?

Tags: function, jquery

Why is the following script not running well?

The function on outside of `$(document).ready` and `window.onload` can't call a function and it's like refresh the page. I am used to the script and it is okay...

```
$(function () {
    $('.media-table').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo":true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": false,
                        "aTargets": [ -1]}],
        "bServerSide":true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'module/view/dataMember.php',
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"datatable-header"fl>t<"datatable-footer"ip>',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "<span>Search:</span> _INPUT_",
            "sLengthMenu": "<span>Show entries:</span> _MENU_",
            "oPaginate": { "sFirst": " First ", "sLast": " Last ", "sNext": " Next ", "sPrevious": " Prev " }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 4 ] }
        ]
    });
});

function rad(){
    var url = "module/master/element.php";
    var form_data = {
        is_ajax: 'radPackage',
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(str)
        {
            $('#radPackageEdit').html(str);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

window.onload = function() {
    rad();
};

function actDetail(Object){
    alert(Object);
    var url = "module/master/controller.php";
    var form_data = {
        ident : Object,
        is_ajax: 'viewer',
        content: 'member'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            data = msg.split("|");
            alert(data);
            $("#idMemberDetail").val(data[0]);
            $("#ktpDetail").val(data[1]);
            $("#nameDetail").val(data[2]);
            $("#address1Detail").val(data[3]);
            $("#genderDetail").val(data[4]);
            $("#telephoneDetail").val(data[5]);
            $("#packageNameDetail").val(data[6]);
            $("#smsServiceDetail").html(data[8]);
            $("#saldoDetail").val(data[7]);
            $("#expiredDetail").html(data[9]);
            $('#modalDetail').modal('show');
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function delDetail(Object){
    alert(Object);
    var url = "module/master/controller.php";
    var form_data = {
        ident : Object,
        is_ajax: 'viewer',
        content: 'member'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            data = msg.split("|");
            alert(data);
            $("#idMemberDelete").val(data[0]);
            $("#ktpDelete").val(data[1]);
            $("#nameDelete").val(data[2]);
            $('#modalDelete').modal('show');
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function actEdit(Object){
    var url = "module/master/controller.php";
    var form_data = {
        ident : Object,
        is_ajax: 'viewer',
        content: 'member'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            data = msg.split("|");
            alert(data);
            $("#idMemberEdit").val(data[0]);
            $("#ktpEdit").val(data[1]);
            $("#nameEdit").val(data[2]);
            $("#address1Edit").val(data[3]);
            $("#genderEdit").val(data[4]);
            $("#telephoneEdit").val(data[5]);
            $("#radPackageEdit").val(data[11]);
            $("#smsServiceEdit").val(data[10]);
            $("#saldoEdit").val(data[7]);
            $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function actDel(){
    var url = "module/master/controller.php";
    var form_data = {
        ident : $.trim($('#idMemberDelete').val()),
        is_ajax: 'delete',
        content: 'member'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data==1){
                delSukses();
                $(".media-table").dataTable().fnDraw();
                clearAll();
            }
            else if(data==0){
                delGagal();
            }
            else{
                inpoServer();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function clearAll(){
    alert('cleardata');
    $("#idMemberDelete").val('');
    $("#nameDelete").val('');
    $("#ktpDelete").val('');
}

function delSukses(){
    $.jGrowl('Data berhasil dihapus!', {
        life: 3000,
        theme: 'growl-success',
        header: 'Success!'
    });
}
function delGagal(){
    $.jGrowl('Data gagal dihapus!', {
        life: 3000,
        theme: 'growl-error',
        header: 'Failed!'
    });
}
function inpoServer(){
    $.jGrowl('Server error, connection timeout!', {
        life: 3000,
        theme: 'growl-warning',
        header: 'Timeout!'
    });
}
function attention(){
    $.jGrowl('Diminta berhati-hati dalam melakukan perubahan dan penghapusan data.', {
        life: 3000,
        theme: 'growl-warning',
        header: 'Perhatian!'
    });
}

function editDetail(){
     var ident = $("#idMemberDetail").val();
     actEdit(ident);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formEdit').submit(function(){
        var url = "module/master/controller.php";
        var form_data = {
            idMember : $.trim($('#idMemberEdit').val()),
            name : $.trim($('#nameEdit').val()),
            ktp : $.trim($('#ktpEdit').val()),
            address1 : $.trim($('#address1Edit').val()),
            gender : $.trim($('#genderEdit').val()),
            phone : $.trim($('#telephoneEdit').val()),
            paketGym : $.trim($('#radPackageEdit').val()),
            smsService : $.trim($('#smsServiceEdit').val()),
            saldo : $.trim($('#saldoEdit').val()),
            is_ajax: 'edit',
            content: 'member'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                if (data==1){
                    addSukses();
                    $(".media-table").dataTable().fnDraw();
                    $('#modalEdit').modal('hide');
                    clearAll();
                  }
                else if(data==2){
                    addData();
                }
                else if(data==0){
                    addGagal();
                }
                  else{
                    inpoServer();
                  }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    function clearAll(){
        $("#idMemberEdit").val('');
        $("#nameEdit").val('');
        $("#ktpEdit").val('');
        $("#address1Edit").val('');
        $("#telephoneEdit").val('+62');
        $("#saldoEdit").val('0');
    }

    function addSukses(){
        $.jGrowl('Data yang Anda Masukkan berhasil disimpan!', {
            life: 3000,
            theme: 'growl-success',
            header: 'Success!'
        });
    }
    function addGagal(){
        $.jGrowl('Data yang Anda Masukkan gagal disimpan, silahkan dicek secara manual inputan anda.', {
            life: 3000,
            theme: 'growl-error',
            header: 'Failed!'
        });
    }
    function addData(){
        $.jGrowl('Data yang Anda Masukkan gagal disimpan, karena data sudah ada.', {
            life: 3000,
            theme: 'growl-error',
            header: 'Failed!'
        });
    }
    function inpoServer(){
        $.jGrowl('Server error, connection timeout!', {
            life: 3000,
            theme: 'growl-warning',
            header: 'Timeout!'
        });
    }
});
```

Look at `function actDel()`. It can't execute delSukses(), and it just only like to refresh the page function, but on `$(document).ready` in `$('#formEdit').submit`, it can execute addSukses() and the other function. What am I doing wrong in this script?

Comment: You should wrap ALL your js-code inside of the $(document).ready

Comment: yes, i think should do it,, but i still confuse to bring my global function to inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: WHY do you want certain function as globals?

Comment: it can aesy to call from button action, right? and i still confuse when i try to bring `actDetail()` inside $(document).ready,,,

Answer (score 0):

Functions defined inside your `$(document).ready` handler will not be visible outside it. You need to either export those functions by returning them from your `document.ready` function and assigning that returned value to a variable (and if you have multiple functions, you'll need to package somehow, inside an object literal for example) or you need to move those functions to outside of your `document.ready` function (which is much easier).

Inside the `document.ready` you should be able to call your functions that are defined outside of it. So even if your functions shouldn't be called until the DOM is loaded, if you only call them from inside `$(document).ready` you should be okay.

For example:

```
function iAmAGlobalFunction() {
   // I can be executed from anywhere
}

var a;

var b = $(function() {
   // Functions defined inside here are not visible outside 

   function iAmLocalToDocReady() {
       // I can't be called from outside the doc ready
   }

   // but if I do this
   a = iAmLocalToDocReady;

   // or if I return it 
   return iAmLocalToDocReady;
}

// now I can call it with
a();
b();
```

In general, you don't want to put all your functions in the global namespace, so most experienced JavaScript developers will enclose all their functions and variables inside a single function that serves to hide them and prevent them from getting accidentally overwritten by other code. jQuery does exactly this by defining the `jQuery` object (which is also aliased as `$`) and having you do everything through it.

Comment: okay, but why my function `editDetail()` can't execute `actEdit()`. It's global function, right? When i execute `editDetail()` it just refresh page not showing my modal,

Comment: @TriyanaSyahfrudin - Object is a reserved keyword in Javascript. Use another variable inside your functions.